# CDI Beans module deployment failed on Tomee with Gradle: couldn't start owb context

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, ejb, apache-tomee

I have a Gradle project. The build runs properly including tests. But when I run the tests only using Intellij Idea, then the tests fail:

```
24-Nov-2020 07:10:59.129 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication CDI Beans module deployment failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
...
24-Nov-2020 07:10:59.130 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/isugf_cross]
javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: couldn't start owb context
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:254)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.build(CdiBuilder.java:43)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:971)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:759)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1309)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1131)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5044)
```

and my build.gradle looks like:

```
plugins {
        id 'java'
        id 'war'
    }
    
    group 'uz.fido_biznes'
    version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
    
    dependencies {
        compileOnly('javax:javaee-web-api:7.0')
        implementation fileTree(dir:'D:\\Husan\\projects_work\\FIDO_EXCHANGE\\userlib', include:'/**/*.jar')
        testImplementation('org.testng:testng:7.1.0')
    }
    
    test {
        useTestNG()
    }
```

Comment: Add full stack trace here. So you can run tests from command line Gradle but it fails when you run it from IDE? Can you also provide full output when you run it from IDE?

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem is solved by deleting and recreating the project.